# When user click browser back button the focus should be where he left in the dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When user is at /node/1

Then he click link '2' which is at the footer.

Then the page loads to /node/2

And the user then click the back button on the browser

Then the focus of he browser should be at the area where the link was clicked. I am unable to find a solution

// This is for usability as our pages are very long.

Comment: You could use localStorage to store the element you want to be focused before redirecting the page and if the user returns to the site, scroll the window to this element and do whatever you need to focuse it in your purposes

Comment: could be like this 
document.getElementById("SomeLinkOnNode1").focus();

Comment: There's far too many unknowns here.  Supply us with some example markup for the first page and we can do something to help, but at the moment this question does you no favours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this uses localstorage to memorize the id of the last clicked link:
http://jsfiddle.net/nf6s43ht/1/

```
if(localStorage['lastclick']===undefined){
    console.log('undefined')
}else{
    $('#'+localStorage['lastclick']).focus()//focus the <a>
}

$('a').click(function(){
    localStorage['lastclick']=$(this).attr('id')//memorize id   
})
```

Comment: I am going to look into local storage if that does not work then I might look into cookies

Answer (score -1):

You can use [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie) to store the [focused element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.activeElement) on the `unload` [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers.onunload).